# Nodejs API architecture cron job

Tags: node.js, rest, api, architecture, cron

I'm building a REST API with Nodejs with MongoDB as database.

This API only have **GET** routes to retrieve data. This data is aggregated from others sources via cron job.

I'm not sure how to correctly implement this and what are the best practices.

- Do i need to create **POST**/**PUT** route to put data in database ?
- Do i need to just put data directly in the database ?

*Edit : (more informations)*

Only the cron jobs would use **POST** route

The cron jobs are getting data from others REST API and some web scraping.

Is it a good idea to have my cron in the same application with the API, or if I have to make another application to manage my cron jobs and populate my database ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an API which can be called using an accessKey for updating the data because you would not want to write your mongo db username and password in a shell file.
But if the cron job is a k8s cron job or just a file written in some programming language which can access the db in secure way and is hosted in the same network then you can go ahead with doing it from cron job.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to control the data flow entirely through API at this point, creating a **POST** route would be the way to go. I am not sure how are your **GET** routes secured - if not at all, consider implementing or at least hard-coding some sort of security for routes that modify your data ([oAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/) or similar).

If you can access the database directly and it's desired, you can just directly insert/update the data.

The second option would be probably quicker, but the first one offers more space for expansion in the future and could be more useful overall. 
So in the end, both options are valid, it's up to preference and your use case.